# Fill A box with <div> of fixed width

Tags: html, css

- Currently i am working on a eCommerce site (i am newbie).
- i am using bootstrap for basic styling.
- the structure is given below.
- The div Of class "nl-row" is dynamic.depending upon the no of items in the db it will increase.
- so i am trying to dynamically center the divs in a ".container" div.
- the "nl-row" is given the width of 300px, so if the ".container" had the width of 1000px, there should be 3 "nl-row" in a row and if the ".container" had the width of 700px there should be 2 "nl-row" in a row and should center themselves in the row.

-Please help Me with this issue.

```
<div id="nl-container-1" class="nl-container">
  <div class="nl-row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="img/250x180.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nl-row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="img/250x180.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nl-row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="img/250x180.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the parent use (display:flex;justify-content:center)for the children use :width 300px)

Comment: brilliant, Thank you. It partially worked . I added this to the css (flex-wrap: wrap;) and it worked as fine.